# Get GridViewRow by DataKeyValue

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

Can we get the GridViewRow given a GridView DataKey Value?

I know we can loop through all rows and get the row, but I need to know if there is a shortcut way to find the row.

For example, we can find Row easily if we have RowIndex. Is there a similar way to find the Row given GridView DataKey Value.

Any help regarding this is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
string str = gvListing.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values["YourDataKeyName"].ToString();
```

Comment: we will not be having "RowIndex", we will just have "DataKeyValue".

Comment: DataKeys are attached with each row (record of datasource) of grid. Without relating it to row how you want to relate it then?